# How to do AWS SSL Renewal through Putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/renew-certificate.html

renew-certificate --certificate-arn  [--cli-input-json ] [--generate-cli-skeleton ]

I tried below command through Putty. but it not worked. Please correct me if anything wrong.

Command:

aws acm renew-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:9999999999:certificate/c3913220-3df6-4g08-9f20-d3gg04591fad

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your version of the CLI, it is likely out of date if the verb does not display yet.

Comment: You mean to update Putty version?

0.71 version installed in Windows 7, 32 bit OS.

PuTTY:
Release 0.71
Build platform: 32-bit x86 Windows
Compiler: clang 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final), emulating Visual Studio 2013 / MSVC++ 12.0 (_MSC_VER=1800)

Comment: I mean update the aws cli version. Whichever host its on run update: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html

Comment: I am using Putty. How to do in Putty?

Comment: Hi PuTTy is simply the software you use to connect to the server via, once you've connected on the server if you run `sudo pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli` that should perform the upgrade for you